# Enable Flash plugin in PyQt5 using QWebEngineSettings

Tags: python-3.x, flash, pyqt5

How can I enable flash plugin in PyQt5 5.8.2?

I tried the next piece of code:

QWebEngineSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)

But I am not able to use flash

Any idea?

Comment: Did you install (Pepper) Flash?